# How to capture only video from audio-video file using gstreamer

Tags: c, gstreamer

I want to capture only video from Audio-Video file that file format are .webm and i am going to convert this into .mp4 format which will be consist of only video file.

gst-launch filesrc location=/home/project/teri_meri_kahaani_theatrical_trailer_2.webm ! decodebin2 ! ffenc_mpeg2video ! mpegvideoparse ! queue ! filesink location=/home/project/h.mp4

I used this pipeline but its not working. please tell me how to do this ...

Thank You 
harshal

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the muxer. Try

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/home/project/teri_meri_kahaani_theatrical_trailer_2.webm ! decodebin2 ! ffenc_mpeg2video ! mpegvideoparse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/home/project/h.mp4
```

Comment: its not working .... WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link mpegvideoparse0 to mp4mux0